# How can I encode an email in arabic using CDO with Classic ASP?

Tags: asp-classic, arabic, cdo.message

I need to send an automated email in arabic using CDO with Classic ASP. I am able to send, but the email arrives with invalid characters. Does anyone had the same issue (or know the right way to do this)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124939/convert-arabic-text-to-html-code-characters?lq=1 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386843/cdosys-and-unicode-in-the-from-field-vbscript

Comment: Thank you Dave! I'll check it now.

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks again. We tried but it didn't work...

Comment: If it didn't work, then you should edit your question to reference the other questions and include what you are doing, what didn't work, and why it didn't work for you (new errors, not the result you wanted, etc.).

Comment: Thanks AnonJr! Right now the client changed his priority so he doesn't need that email anymore, so we stop for now. Thanks!